# Validate input with any function in a list

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, composition, function-composition

Say I want to validate an input that has to satisfy one of a number of functions. What is the best way to do this in F#? Here’s a little example I came up with.

```
let funcs = 
            [
                fun x -> x % 2 = 0
                fun x -> x % 3 = 0
                fun x -> x % 5 = 0
            ]

let oneWorks x = funcs |> List.tryFind (fun f -> f x = true) |> Option.isSome

oneWorks 2 //true
oneWorks 3 //true
oneWorks 5 //true
oneWorks 7 //false
```

Comment: What you have is fine, apart from the `= true` bit, which is redundant.

Comment: You could also simplify it by using [List.exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.exists%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), then you'll avoid Option.isSome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, what you have will work fine.

However, I would simplify it to:

```
let any x = funcs |> Seq.exists (fun f -> f x)

any 2 //true
any 3 //true
any 5 //true
any 7 //false
```

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: This question and answer are about `any`. `all` is very similar `let all x = funcs |> Seq.forall (fun f -> f x)`. Both `any` and `all` short-circuit, preventing unnecessary work.